# To check if a number is n choose r

Tags: combinatorics, largenumber, integer-arithmetic

Is there an efficient way to find the number n, given a number N (may be as large as 10^18) which is equal to nCr for some n and r ? How do we find the corresponding minimum value of n? for instance

```
f(20)=6 (20=6C3)  
f(21)= 7 (21=7C2)  
f(22)= 22 (22=22C1)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was looking for an algorithm, not just a mathematical solution. SO, I thought this would be a better place.

Comment: I would try cross posting for the mathematical solution there, the algorithm here, and if a mathematical solution is presented @math, then update this with that information for a quicker algorithmic answer. neat question, though

Answer (score 0):

To find minimum n is same as to find maximum r with `r<=n/2`. Since `nCr` is bounded from below with `(2r)Cr=(2r)!/r!`, number of r's to check is finite. For `10^18` maximum r is 31, since `64C32=1.8*10^18`.

To find n, for given r, that satisfies N=nCr, it is possible to check is `N*r!` of form `n*(n-1)*...*(n-r+1)`. n is near `(N*r!)^(1/r) + r/2`. I think with few checks it can be tested.

**Update:**

Simple python implementation:

```
from operator import mul  # or mul=lambda x,y:x*y
from fractions import Fraction

def nCk(n,k):
  return int(reduce(mul, (Fraction(n-i, i+1) for i in range(k)), 1))
def M(f,t):
  return reduce(mul, range(f,t+1), 1)

def find_n_r(N):
  for r in range(2, 50): # omit 1, since it is trivial solution
    if nCk(2*r, r) > N:
      return False
    Nr = N * M(1,r)
    nn = pow(Nr, 1./r) + r*0.5
    n = int(nn)
    if M(n-r+1,n) == Nr:
      return n, r
    n += 1
    if M(n-r+1,n) == Nr:
      return n, r  

print find_n_r(nCk(31,7))
print find_n_r(nCk(31,7) + 12)
```

prints:

```
(31, 7)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give a pseudo-code. This algorithm does the task in O((N log N)<sup>2</sup>) time. It is not fast enough, but I have listed some optimizations that can boost the speed significanntly. Maybe someone could optimize this further.

The key here is that we can determine the highest power of a prime number p that divides n! for some n,p without computing the value of n!, by just looking at n, in O(log n) time. We denote the highest power of p that divides n! by hdp(n,p). hdp(n,p) can be computed as:
hdp(n,p) = floor(n/p) + floor(n/p<sup>2</sup>)+.... Thus hdp(n,p) can be computed in log<sub>p</sub>n time.

First we compute the list of prime numbers less than or equal to n.
Then, we find all prime factors of N. This will be easier because you computed prime numbers upto N in step 1. Let N = p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>a<sub>2</sub></sup>...p<sub>k</sub><sup>a<sub>k</sub></sup>.

The upper and lower bounds for n are given by Ante in his solution. We call them n<sub>max</sub> and n<sub>min</sub> respectively. Then we iterate for all n between n<sub>min</sub> and n<sub>max</sub>, for all r between 1 to n. Now, N = <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub> = (n!)/((n-r)!*r!) if and only if hdp(n,p<sub>i</sub>) - hdp(k,p<sub>i</sub>) - hdp(n-k,p<sub>i</sub>) = a<sub>i</sub> for all i. So an n-r pair can be pruned in at most O((log n)<sup>2</sup>) time. Starting with the largest prime factors should be better idea for the degree should be small then.

Some optimizations:

1. for any n, you can find the range in which r can lie, instead of iterating for all r from 1 to n. Use inequalities like <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub> > (n/r)<sup>r</sup> etc.
2. No need to consider values of n less than p<sub>k</sub> where p<sub>k</sub> is the largest prime factor of N.
3. Solve for <sup>n</sup>C<sub>2</sub> = N separately (It is just a quadratic equation). Now, only consider the values of n that are smaller than this solution.  the solution will be of O(N<sup>1/2</sup>), so that will reduce the time complexity to O(N(log n)<sup>2</sup>). Doing this for both <sup>n</sup>C<sub>2</sub> = N and <sup>n</sup>C<sub>3</sub> = N will reduce the time complexity to O(N<sup>2/3</sup>(log n)<sup>2</sup>) and so on.